# How to input information into a single cell of a column in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to create a new column and input information only into the first cell of that column, instead of filling in the entire column with that information?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
col1 col2 col3 
 25   A   TRUE
      B   FALSE
      A   TRUE
```

But this is what I keep getting instead:

```
col1 col2 col3 
 25   A   TRUE
 25   B   FALSE
 25   A   TRUE
```

Here is the code I am using, but as I said, it fills the entire column.

`df$col1 <- mean(age)`

I tried using this next line of code to just input the information into the first cell but it is not working and I was hoping for a more streamlined approach vs. having to mess with the column/row numbers.

`df$col1[1,1] <- mean(age)`

Thoughts? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you'd have to do it in 2 steps - `df$col1 <- NA` and then `df$col1[1] <- 25` - does that give you the result you wanted? (as long as we're clear that there is no such thing as an 'empty' cell/part-of-vector in R - you either have an `NA` or a value.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a `list`. It will give you the structure you want, including different-length entries.
Keep in mind that a data frame is also just a list-collection, but with columns of the same length.

```
age <- c(0, 50)

c(col1 = mean(age), Map(unlist, df))
$col1
[1] 25

$col2
[1] "A" "B" "A"

$col3
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(col2 = c("A", "B", "A"), col3 = c(TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.frame` has to have columns with the same length. You can fill up the remaining rows with `NA`.

```
df <- data.frame(col2=c("A","B","A"), col3=c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE))

df$col1 <- NA
df$col1[1] <- 25

df
#  col2  col3 col1
#1    A  TRUE   25
#2    B FALSE   NA
#3    A  TRUE   NA
```